# How to convert date time string in formatted date time in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a string of Date and Time ("2017-11-29 11:08:43" YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) like this. I want to convert it into "29-11 11:08"(DD-MM hh:mm) format.
I tried it using below code. But not get any success. have you any solution?

```
convert: function (idleFrom) {
            var date = Ext.Date.parse(idleFrom, "Y-m-d");
            return date;
        }
```

Comment: Ext.Date.format(new Date("2017-11-29"), "d-m h:m");

Answer (score 0):

first change your string into date format using

```
var dt = new Date(idleFrom)
```

than change into you required format using

```
Ext.Date.format(dt, 'm/d/Y');
```

follw this link for more [format](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-format)

Hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string, and want it reformatted, you have to parse the string into a JS date object first, and then format the JS date object into the string representation you need:

```
var date = Ext.Date.parse("2017-11-29 11:08:43", "Y-m-d H:i:s")
var str = Ext.Date.format(date, "m/d/Y")
```

Please note that `Ext.Date.parse` is really picky regarding the format identifier. If the matching between the format identifier and the input string's format is not 100%, your date will be `null`.

E.g. `Ext.Date.parse("2017-11-29 11:08:43", "Y-m-d H:i")` will be null because the seconds are in the date string, but missing from the format identifier.